# GWAN unescape_html()

Tags: html, escaping, g-wan

Code snip:

```
U8 test[20] = "+45%201234%205678";
printf("\n%s\n",test);
unescape_html(test);
printf("%s\n",test);
```

Output

```
+45%201234%205678
45 1234 5678
```

Where did my "+" sign go? Error or feature?

Comment: WebnetMobile.com's answere put me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in URL encoding `+` is used to substitute space. Ensure you do not get `" 45 1234 5678"` in fact.

Comment: Thanks a lot - JS replace("+","%2B") on .value make the old lady sing again.

Answer (score 1):

When a URL is encoded the `+` sign indicates a space so your function `unescape_html()` is removing the `+` sign

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/?text=A+blue+sky&something_else=A+red+sky
```